# Xamarin.form setpage not worked second time

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I create new mobile app using xamarin form. I have to create two pages login screen and home screen.
I get sample from [Here](https://github.com/conceptdev/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/LoginDemo)

But when i create same I cant go second page. it always stay login page only.

In my android MainActivity code

```
   public class MainActivity : AndroidActivity, LoginManager
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);

        SetPage(App.GetLoginPage(this));
      // SetPage(App.GetLoginPage(this));


    }
    #region ILoginManager implementation
    public void ShowMainPage()
    {
        SetPage(App.GetHomePage(this));
    }

    public void Logout()
    {
        SetPage(App.GetLoginPage(this));
    }
    #endregion
}
```

setPage method called second time but page content not replaced. Please help any one

Comment: The Xamarin.Forms framework handles the Navigation for you. You should use the Xamarin.Forms.Navigation class to manage the Navigation Stack, and avoid using SetPage in the Android Project,

Answer (score 0):

Here is a work around to the second set page problem with Android. Create a second interface and instead of using set page on the existing activity start a new activity where OnCreate of the new activity calls set page and finish the current activity.

**App.cs**

```
    public static ILoginManager LoginManager;
    public static IAppNavigation SplashManger;      


    public static Page GetLoginPage(ILoginManager lmanager)
    {
        LoginManager = lmanager;          
        return new Page_Login();
    }

    public static Page GetShowSplashPage(IAppNavigation iSplashNavigation)
    {
        SplashManger = iSplashNavigation;
        return new Page_Splash();
    }
```

**Android MainActivty**

```
[Activity(Label = "", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize |   ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
public class MainActivity : AndroidActivity, IAppNavigation
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        //Window.RequestFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        SetPage(App.GetShowSplashPage(this));
    }



    public void GetLoginPage()
    {
        StartActivity(new Intent(this, typeof(LoginActivity)));
        Finish();
    }
```

**Android LoginActivity**

```
[Activity(Label = "", ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
public class LoginActivity : AndroidActivity, ILoginManager
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        SetPage(App.GetLoginPage(this));
    }



    public void GetMainMenu()
    {
        StartActivity(new Intent(this, typeof(MainMenuActivity)));
        Finish();
    }
```

In iOS you do not need to do anything special just implement all necessary interfaces you are going to use in App delegate.

**iOS AppDelegate**

```
[Register("AppDelegate")]
public partial class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate, ILoginManager, IAppNavigation
{
    // class-level declarations
    UIWindow window;


    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        Forms.Init();

        window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

        window.RootViewController = App.GetShowSplashPage(this).CreateViewController();

        window.MakeKeyAndVisible();

        return true;
    }

    public void GetMainMenu()
    {
        window.RootViewController = App.GetMainMenu().CreateViewController();
        window.MakeKeyAndVisible();
    }

    public void GetLoginPage()
    {
        window.RootViewController = App.GetLoginPage(this).CreateViewController();
        window.MakeKeyAndVisible();
    }
```